# How to add a letter the end of each word per its word index?

Tags: java

I have a problem about adding a letter the end of each word per its word index.

I cannot handle with that. How can I fix it?

Here is my code shown below.

```
for(int i=0;i<sentenceOfArray.length;i++) {
    sentenceOfArray[i] = sentenceOfArray[i] + "c";
}
```

Comment: Can you show a clear input/output example please? Also, why do you think that the code did not work? Please share the code that actually shows the result as well, I suspect the issue might be there maybe. Your description is kinda broad and unclear (at least to me). Voting to close, since unclear. Tldr, create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution with the usage of `repeat` method.

```
for(int i=0;i<sentenceOfArray.length;i++) {
    sentenceOfArray[i] = sentenceOfArray[i] + "a".repeat(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Your answer shows how important it is to ask a clear and specific question. `How to add a letter` as opposed to `How to add letters` is only a small change, but it can lead to completely different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach:

```
 String [] sentenceOfArray  = {"abg", "ert", "mlk"};
 for(int i=0;i<sentenceOfArray.length;i++) {
     char lastLetter = sentenceOfArray[i].charAt(sentenceOfArray[i].length() - 1);
    sentenceOfArray[i] = sentenceOfArray[i] + "c";
     System.out.println(sentenceOfArray[i]+"\n");
  }
```

Output:

abgc

ertc

mlkc